# Permission denied when executing a directory

Tags: debian, shell, command-line

I've been working with Docker and Kubernetes in a Linux file system and trying to execute an executable file (which turned out to be a directory).
I would get a "Permission Denied" error which made me think that I messed up permissions, but as I checked it, everything was correct.
Later I noticed that it was a directory I was trying to execute.

My question is, how reasonable it's to have a "Permission Denied" error in this case instead of something like "Can't execute a directory" or something similar?

I'm not very experienced in Linux thus this question can seem very newbie to you but thanks beforehand for your answers.

Distro: Debian 10. FS: ext4

Comment: The [documentation of `execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) specifies `EACCES` for *"The file or a script interpreter is not a regular file."* and other errors. This error code is translated to the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

"Permission denied" is the EACCES error code, the one you usually get if file permission bits don't grant you the requested access.

You're right that here, something like EISDIR ("Is a directory") might make more sense. For the more general case, e.g. with a FIFO, you'd need something else, maybe ENOEXEC could do, even though the error messages for it now refer to the file format ("Exec format error" in Linux). It's the one you get for a regular file you have enough permissions for, but which the OS doesn't recognize.

I don't think there's a standard error for "Not a regular file".

Anyway it's [specified as EACCES in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html):

> [EACCES].
> The new process image file is not a regular file and the implementation does not support execution of files of its type.

Without knowing if there is a real logical reason behind the choice, I'd suggest a usual reason in cases like this is that it was done that way the first time, copied to all other systems, and then kept for compatibility. It's not likely the only error code that doesn't fully 100 % match.